# mismatch in local date conversion to utc epoch time and back to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc, epoch, date-conversion

let the local date time be `local : Mar 10 2014 11:52:50 GMT+0530`

converting it to utc epoch time in javascript:

```
var epochtime=Date.UTC(2014,2,10,11,52,50);
```

`output : 1394452370000`

now converting it back to local date:

```
var utcSeconds =1394452370000;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
alert(d);
```

`output : Fri Jun 09 46158 06:03:20 GMT+0530`

but required output is : `Mar 10 2014 11:52:50 GMT+0530`

please could someone figure out what the problem is ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milliseconds != seconds. You're getting a value in milliseconds, but then using it as seconds.

To turn your value back into a date, simply:

```
var d = new Date(1394452370000);
```

Example:

```js
var epochtime=Date.UTC(2014,2,10,11,52,50);
var d = new Date(epochtime);
snippet.log(d.toISOString());
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried , date is ok but still time mismatch is there  ..  Mar 10 2014 17:22:50

Comment: so can't we use setUTCSeconds for this purpose and if so why what is the difference

Comment: @jacquel: See the above. The resulting `Date` object has exactly the time you specified. Note that the `toString` of `Date` instances always gives you *local time*, so if you want to see the UTC time, you have to use the UTC or ISO methods.

Comment: @jacquel: *Again:* Milliseconds != seconds. If you really want to use `setUTCSeconds`, you'll need to divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: thank you very much for clarification,.,., i didn't knew the input was in milli,.,.,

Comment: @jacquel: Not the *input*, the *output* (of `Date.UTC`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try directly converting the UTC to Date,

var d = new Date(utcSeconds);
alert(d);